# Button Click force close the application

Tags: android, button

Whenever I click the button 1 , the application crashes(force closes). I am not able to figure out the reason. Changing the directory to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/test.3gp" is also not working.
The code is:

```
package com.example.newaa;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.os.Environment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class Record extends Activity{
    Button btn1,btn2;
    MediaRecorder recorder;
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.record);
            btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    recorder = new MediaRecorder();

                    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/test.3gp");
                    //recorder.setOutputFile("file:///sdcard/sample.3gp");

                //  recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
                    //recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

                    try {
                        recorder.prepare();
                        recorder.start();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    recorder.stop();
                    recorder.reset();
                    recorder.release();

                    recorder = null;
                }
            });
     }

}
```

The logcat is

```
07-05 11:36:35.050: E/AndroidRuntime(220): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to 
uncaught exception
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220): java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(Native Method)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at com.example.newaa.Record$1.onClick(Record.java:56)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-05 11:36:35.070: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: make sure you have  `<android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO">` in manifast.xml

Comment: hve u given <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" /> in manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying it on Simulator,if yes, I would suggest you to give it a try on Real device.
May be it is just due to Simulator. As i faced such issue long back on Simulator but On phone it was working fine

Missing permission >> [audio permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECORD_AUDIO) in Manifest could be another reason.

Answer (score 0):

I got the reason. Was too easy i suppose :P

I missed the permission in the manifest file

Comment: This is the bad way that after getting answer of your question, you post your own answer instead of accepting the answer which helped you. it will result you getting less responses

Comment: I did accept the answer as well. Also, I had not refreshed. I am well aware of the rules .